# How many balls to draw to ensure balls of same color?

Tags: pigeonhole-principle

We have a bag which contains $5$ red balls, $8$ blue balls, $10$ white balls, $12$ green balls and $7$ yellow balls. How many balls should we pick to ensure

- a) at least **4** balls have the **same color**?
- b) at least **6** balls have the **same color**?
- c) at least **7** balls have the **same color**?
- d) at least **9** balls have the **same color**?

---

I think I solved the a) part.
If we pick a ball every time till we reach $4$ balls with the same color it takes us $15+1$ balls.

But I don't understand the other parts.
Can you guys help me?
It will mean A LOT  to me.
Thanks

Comment: Part (b) works exactly like part (a).  Part (c) and (d), note that there are only so many red and yellow balls available.  Think of the "worst case scenario" where you have drawn as many balls as possible of each color while still avoiding the "at least X balls of the same color" condition.

Comment: While the "worst case scenario" for drawing at least four of some color is to have drawn three of every color ball, the "worst case scenario" for drawing at least 9 balls of each color does not involve drawing 8 red balls since that is impossible but rather to have drawn all five possible red balls, and then the eight blue balls, eight of the white balls, etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We look at the worst possible case, and draw one more ball.

1. Worst possible case was drawing $3$ balls of each of five colors first, before reaching to fourth ball of some color. Hence $3\cdot5+1$
2. Worst case includes drawing all 5 of red balls, then five each of other colors. Hence $5\cdot5+1$
3. $\, \ldots$

Similarly, can you proceed?

Comment: if we omit 5 red balls because its impossible to have 6 red balls the we start picking colors one by one till we reach 6 balls with same color will be 24+1 balls which is 25 right?

Comment: But we are picking out balls without knowing the color. So red balls can be picked; they must be taken into account.

Comment: For b), as we have only four other colors, $5+5\cdot4+1=26$.

Comment: We pick one less, then add one in the end. That final ball counts as 6th ball.

Comment: so for d  it will be 5(red)+7(blue)+8(yellow)+8*2+1=37

Comment: Last time we picked 5 of each, then final ball became 6th. This time we pick 6 of each. Then last ball will become 7th.

Comment: i mean for 9 balls with the same color

Comment: Yes that's correct!

Comment: when i upvote it this message shws up "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."

Comment: No problem, thanks!

Comment: another question sorry for a asking a lot by extended pigeon hole principle [m/n] or n<=m*k+1 how can we solve these using n<=m*k+1(m is holes and n pigeons)